# In Word 2010, how can I insert an icon or text in the margin that is anchored to a paragraph?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, styles

In technical books or documents you often see little icons in the margin that indicate some property of the paragraph.

How would I add that in Word 2010 in such a way that it is displayed in the margin and stays anchored to the paragraph?

Here is an example from Code Complete by Steve McConnell with two such icons: KEY POINT and CODING HORROR.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a floating image (with square wrapping for example) and anchor it to the paragraph (enable paragraph markers to do this). Then under wrapping options -> Advanced change the left and top positions to be relative to the paragraph. Adjust the position so it's inside the margin and it should work as expected.

Comment: Yup, anchor to paragraph is what I was looking for.